# Shell redirection i/o order

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I'm playing with i/o shell redirection. The commands I've tried (in bash):

```
ls -al *.xyz 2>&1 1> files.lst
```

and

```
ls -al *.xyz 1> files.lst 2>&1
```

There is no any `*.xyz` file in current folder.

These commands gives me the different results. The first command shows an error message `ls: *.xyz: No such file or directory` on the screen. But the second one prints this error message to the file. Why did the first command failed to write an err output to the file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This error:

```
ls: *.xyz: No such file or directory
```

is being written on `stderr` by `ls` binary.

However in this command:

```
ls -al *.xyz 2>&1 1> files.lst
```

**You're first redirecting** `stderr` to `stdout` which by default goes to `tty` (terminal)

And then you're redirecting `stdout` to a file `files.lst`, however remember that stderr doesn't redirected to file since you have `stderr` to `stdout` redirection **before** `stdout` to `file` redirection. Your `stderr` still gets written to `tty` in this case.

However in 2nd case you change the order of redirections (first `stdout` to `file` and then `stderr` to `stdout`) and that rightly redirects `stderr` to a `file` which is also being used by `stdout`.

Comment: Stdout is NOT by default a tty.  It is simply inherited from the shell.  If the shell is interactive and running on a tty, then stdout and stderr default to that tty.  If the shell is not running on a tty, then they do not.  I realize this seems like a nit, but it is important not to conflate stdout with a terminal, and people make that mistake very often.

Comment: Yes I meant in the context of an interactive shell since OP is running this command in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 50):

The [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) has a clear example (similar to yours) to show that the order matters and also explains the difference. Here's the relevant part excerpted (emphasis mine):

> Note that the order of redirections is significant. For example, the
>   command
>
> ls > *dirlist* 2>&1
>
> directs both standard output (file descriptor 1) and standard error
>   (file descriptor 2) to the file *dirlist*, while the command
>
> ls 2>&1 > *dirlist*
>
> directs only the standard output to file *dirlist*, because the **standard
>   error was made a copy of the standard output before the standard
>   output was redirected to *dirlist*.**

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14249/30580) explains it from the POSIX viewpoint.

Confusions happen due to a key difference. `>` redirects *not* by making left operand (`stderr`) point to right operand (`stdout`) but by making a copy of the right operand and assigning it to the left. Conceptually, assignment by copy and not by reference.

So reading from left-to-right which is how this is interpreted by Bash: `ls > dirlist 2>&1` means redirect `stdout` to the file `dirlist`, followed by redirection of `stderr` to whatever `stdout` is currently (which is already the file `dirlist`). However, `ls 2>&1 > dirlist` would redirect `stderr` to whatever `stdout` is currently (which is the screen/terminal) and then redirect `stdout` to `dirlist`.

Answer (score 22):

Redirections are:

- processed *from left to right*.
- interpreted *iteratively*:

  - an *earlier* redirection can affect a *later* one:

    - if an earlier redirection has redirected a given stream (identified by a file descriptor number, such as `1` for stdout (the default), and `2` for stderr), later redirections targeting that stream refer to the already-redirected version.
  - but *not vice versa* - a later redirection has no retroactive effect on the the target of an earlier redirection:

    - e.g., if you specify file descriptor `1` as the target in an earlier redirection, what `1` means *at that time* is locked in, even if `1` is redirected later.
- Note, however, that output isn't actually sent until *all* redirections are in place, and that any redirection-target output files are created or truncated *before* command execution begins (this is the reason why you can't read from and redirect output to the same file with a single command).

Applied to the example from the question:

- `>file 2>&1`:

  - `>file` *first* redirects stdout (file descriptor `1`, implied by not prefixing `>` with a file descriptor number) to output file `file`
  - `2>&1` *then* redirects stderr (`2`) to the *already redirected* stdout (`1`).
  - The net effect is that *both* original streams end up in `file`.
- `2>&1 >file`:

  - `2>&1` first redirects stderr to the *then-original* stdout; since file descriptor `2` participates in no further redirections, stderr output will therefore go to whatever stdout was defined as *at that point* - i.e., the *original* stdout, given that this is the first redirection.

    - Technically, the original stdout file descriptor is *duplicated*, and that duplicate is what stderr then refers to, which explains why it isn't affected by a later redirection of stdout.
  - `>file` then redirects the original stdout to `file` - but that has no effect anymore on the already locked-in redirection of stderr.
  - The net effect is that only sent-directly-to-stdout output is captured in `file`, while sent-to-stderr output is output to (the original, unredirected) stdout.

Answer (score 2):

Because order does matter.
In the first case, you first redirect stderr (2) to stdout (1).
Then you redirect (1) to a file. But stderr (2) is still pointed to stdout of the shell running the command. Pointing (1) to a file in this case doesn't change the output device that (2) is directed at, so it still goes to terminal.

In the second case, you redirect stdout (1) to a file. Then you point stderr (2) to the same place 1 is pointed, which is the file, so the error message goes to the file.

Comment: Mostly correct, but I question the wording of 4th sentence "But stderr is still pointed to stdout"  After fd 1 is redirected to the file, fd 2 is still tied to the file (a tty is a file) that the shell's stdout is associated with, but not the stdout of the command.  Perhaps change that sentence to read 'stderr is still pointed to stdout of the shell running the command'.  More importantly, do not conflate stdout with a terminal.  It is often a terminal, but (probably more often) not.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Agreed, I've made your edit. It was probably reasonable in this specific case, but not a good generic answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Redirections are processed from left to right

they are the same:

- my_cmd 1>a_file
- my_cmd  >a_file

---

My method to remember the whole thing

let's imagine  we are playing a game.
There is a bridge with 2 broken parts.

1. If we first place a block named `2>&1` to repair the first broken part, the ball named `stderrr` can arrive the place named `stdout`, but since the second part is still broken,  `stderrr` will fall down to a river named `tty` (to your screen) .Then we place a block named `1>a_file` to repair the second broken part, the ball named `stdout` can arrive the place named `a_file`
2. If we first place a block named `1>a_file` to repair the second broken part and then repair the first broken part with `2>&1`,  the ball `stderrr` will not fall down to the river `tty`
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

First

```
$ ls *.xyz 2>&1 >files.lst
ls: cannot access '*.xyz': No such file or directory
$ cat files.lst
```

This writes the ls error message to the terminal because when `2>&1` copies stdout to stderr they both still points to the terminal. `files.lst` is empty because stderr is not pointing to this file but to the terminal.

Next

```
$ ls *.xyz >files.lst 2>&1
$ cat files.lst
ls: cannot access '*.xyz': No such file or directory
```

Here `>files.lst` redirects stdout to the file `files.lst`. Then `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout which now points to `files.lst`.

So when you cat the file it now contains the ls error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -al *.xyz 2>&1 1> files.lst
```

In the first example, `2>&1` redirection just points stderr to screen.

```
ls -al *.xyz 1> files.lst 2>&1
```

Here though, this has an effect of `ls -al *.xyz &>files.lst`. Both stdout and stderr are passed to files.lst file.

The difference is the *order* of redirections.