# Bash: Pipe stdout and catch stderr into a variable

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

Is it possible to pipe normal `stdout` further to another program, but store `stderr` into a variable?

This is the usecase:

```
mysqldump database | gzip > database.sql
```

In this scenario I would like to catch all errors/warnings produced by `mysqldump` and store them into a variable, but the normal `stdout` (which is the dump) should continue being piped to `gzip`.

Any ideas about how to accomplish this?

Comment: you could try to redirect stream 1 and 2 to different destinations and read stderr file into a var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
errors=$(mysqldump database 2>&1 > >(gzip > database.sql))
```

Here, I'm using process substitution to get `gzip` to use `mysqldump`'s output as stdin. Given [the order of redirections (`2>&1` before `>`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17975577/2072269), `mysqldump`'s stderr should now be used for the command substitution.

Testing it out:

```
$ a=$(sh -c 'echo foo >&2; echo bar' 2>&1 > >(gzip > foo))
$ gunzip < foo
bar
$ echo $a
foo
```

Comment: Is it also possible to store both exit codes and both error messages (of `mysqldump` and also of `gzip`) so I can check on them separately afterwards?

Comment: @lockdoc not using this way, I'm afraid. You can get `mysqldump`'s exit codes using `$?`, but the `gzip` status is lost.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
mysqldump database 2> dump_errors | gzip > database.sql
error_var=$( cat dump_errors )
rm dump_errors
```

Here, all errors by `mysqldump` are redirected to a file called 'dump_errors', and stdout is piped to `gzip`, which in turn writes to `database.sql`.

Contents of 'dump_errors' are then assigned to variable 'error_val', and file 'dump_errors' is then removed.

---

Note the following redirections:

```
$ sort 1> output 2> errors   # redirects stdout to "output", stderr to "errors"
$ sort 1> output 2>&1        # stderr goes to stdout, stdout writes to "output"
$ sort 2> errors 1>&2        # stdout goes to stderr, stderr writes to "errors"

$ sort 2>&1 > output         # tie stderr to screen, redirect stdout to "output"
$ sort > output 2>&1         # redirect stdout to "output", tie stderr to "output"
```

Comment: Is this possible without the need of an extra file?

Comment: Check out muru's solution. In general, if you want to use pipes, then you can't create variables within the pipes since the pipe runs in a subshell and variables will not persist once you exit, hence the need for the extra file. But if you don't use a pipe, then you can do away with the extra file.

Comment: Thanks for your additional information. However, I am going to accept muru's answer as it does all stuff without tmpfies.