# Meaning of open( STDERR, ">&STDOUT" )

Tags: perl, io-redirection

i find this in one sample script,
then i search from google and found the following words,

> Note that you cannot simply open STDERR to be a dup of STDOUT in your Perl 
>       program and avoid calling the shell to do the redirection. This doesn't 
>       work:
>
> ```
> open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT");
> ```
>
> This fails because the open() makes STDERR go to where STDOUT was going at 
>       the time of the open(). The backticks then make STDOUT go to a string, but 
>       don't change STDERR (which still goes to the old STDOUT).

Now I am confused. What exactly is the meaning of `open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT");` ?

Comment: https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#open-FILEHANDLE%2CEXPR

Comment: The stuff you quote "from google" mentions backticks, but you don't show that part of what it was talking about; I suspect that will help it make more sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `&` in the mode `>&` in the call

```
open STDERR, ">&STDOUT";  # or: open STDERR, ">&", \*STDOUT
```

the first given filehandle is made a copy of the second one. See [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), and see `man 2 dup2` since this goes via `dup2` syscall. The notation follows the shell's [I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).
 Since here the first filehandle exists (`STDERR`)<sup>†</sup> it is first closed.

The effect is that prints to `STDERR` will go to where `STDOUT` was going before this was done, with the side effect of the original `STDERR` being closed.

This is legit and does not result in errors but *is not a good way to redirect `STDERR` in general* -- after that we cannot restore `STDERR` any more. See [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) for how to redirect `STDERR`.

The rest of the comment clearly refers to a situation where backticks (see [qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)), which redirect `STDOUT` of the executed command(s) to the program, are used after that `open` call. All this seems to refer to an idea of redirecting `STDERR` to `STDOUT` in this way.

Alas, the `STDERR`, made by that `open` call to go where `STDOUT` was going, doesn't get redirected by the backticks and thus still goes "there."  In my case prints to `STDERR` wind up on the terminal as I see the warning (`ls: cannot access...`) with

```
perl -we'open STDERR, ">&STDOUT"; $out = qx(ls no_such)'
```

(unlike with `perl -we'$out = qx(ls no_such 2>&1)'`). Explicit prints to `STDERR` also go to the terminal as `STDOUT` (add such prints and redirect output to a file to see).

This may be expected since `&` made a *copy* of the filehandle, so the "new" one (the former `STDERR`) still goes where `STDOUT` was going, that is to the terminal. What is of course unintended in this case and thus an error.

---

<sup>†</sup> Every program in UNIX gets connected to standard streams `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`, with file descriptors `0`, `1`, and `2` respectively.  In a Perl program we then get ready filehandles for these, like the `STDERR` (for fd 2).

Some generally useful posts on manipulations of file descriptors in the shell:

- [What does “3>&1 1>&2 2>&3” do in a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42728/what-does-31-12-23-do-in-a-script)
- [In the shell, what does “ 2>&1 ” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean?)
- [File descriptors & shell scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/file-descriptors-shell-scripting)
- [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections)
- [Shell redirection i/o order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975232/shell-redirection-i-o-order)

Answer (score 2):

It's basically `dup2(fileno(STDOUT), fileno(STDERR))`. See your system's `dup2` man page.

In short, it associates `STDERR` with the same stream as `STDOUT` at the system level. After the command is performed writing to either will be the same as writing to `STDOUT` before the change.

Unless someone's messed with STDOUT or STDERR, it's equivalent to the shell command

```
exec 2>&1
```