# Bash Command Runs Manually But NOT in Crontab

Tags: bash, cron, command

On a CentOS 7.2 server the following command runs successfully manually -

```
scp usrname@storage-server:/share/Data/homes/AWS/2301KM-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").csv /home/vyv/data/AWS/ 2>&1 >> /home/vyv/data/AWS/scp-log.txt
```

This command simply takes the file that has the current date in its filename from a directory on a remote server and stores it to a directory on the local server and prints out the log file in the same directory.

Public key authentication is setup so there is no prompt for the password when run manually.

I have it configured in crontab to run 3 minutes after the top of every hour as in the following format -

```
3 * * * * scp usrname@storage-server:/share/Data/homes/AWS/2301KM-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").csv /home/vyv/data/AWS/ 2>&1 >> /home/vyv/data/AWS/scp-log.txt
```

However, I wait patiently and don't see any files being downloaded automatically.

I've checked the /var/log/cron logs and see an entry on schedule like this -

```
Feb 9 17:30:01 intranet CROND[9380]: (wzw) CMD (scp usrname@storage-server:/share/Data/homes/AWS/2301KM-$(date +")
```

There are other similar jobs set in crontab that work perfectly.

Can anyone offer suggestions/clues on why this is not working?

Gratefully,
Rakesh.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: `%` is a special character in a cronjob. Escape it with a backslash.

Comment: Try making a bash file to run the job and run that fron Cron. That way you can test the script first.

Comment: `2>&1 >>somefile` doesn't do what you want; you need to put the `2>&1` *after* the `>>somefile`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975232/shell-redirection-i-o-order).

Answer (score 0):

Use full path for `scp` (or any other binary) in crontab:

```sh
3 * * * * /usr/bin/scp usrname@storage-server:/share/Data/homes/AWS/2301KM-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").csv /home/vyv/data/AWS/ 2>&1 >> /home/vyv/data/AWS/scp-log.txt
```

Comment: Hello Piotr, thank you for your response. I tried that and it is still not working.