# why the command; ls -l file_doesnot_exists > /dev/null 2>&1 is working while; ls -l 2>&1 file_doesnot_exists > /dev/null is not

Tags: linux, bash, powershell-core

I'm just wondring how to know which instruction we normally put first in a shell command ?
for example,
why the command:

`ls -l file_doesnot_exists > /dev/null 2>&1`

is working, while this command :

`ls -l 2>&1 file_doesnot_exists > /dev/null`

is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:

- The question is tagged `linux`, which means that `ls` is *not* a  built-in alias of PowerShell's own `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet (which applies on *Windows* only) and instead refers to the standard `/bin/ls` Unix utility.

---

- In ***PowerShell*** there is *no* difference between your commands, because the ***order* of [redirections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) does NOT matter**.

  - All targeted [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) always retain their identity: any redirection of a stream affects any other redirections to the same stream in the same command.
  - Therefore, ***neither* of your commands work as intended and produce *no output***, because while `2>&1` redirects the error stream (`2`) into the success output stream (`1`), the latter's output is ultimately *discarded*, due to `> /dev/null` (`>` is the same as `1>`), *including* the redirected error-stream output.
- By contrast, in ***POSIX-compatible shells* such as Bash**, the ***order* of redirections DOES matter**:

  - `ls -l 2>&1 file_doesnot_exists > /dev/null` **WORKS** as intended:

    - `2>&1` redirects stderr output to the *original* stdout.
    - The *later* redirection of stdout (`>` is the same as `1>`) has *no* effect on `2>&1`
    - The net effect is that only *stderr* lines print to stdout, while stdout lines are discarded (by the redirection to `/dev/null`).
  - By contrast, `ls -l file_doesnot_exists > /dev/null 2>&1` **DOES NOT** and produces *no output*:

    - `> /dev/null` redirects stdout to `/dev/null`, i.e. effectively *discards* stdout output.
    - Because `2>&1` comes *later* in the command, `1` refers to the *already redirected* stdout, so that stderr output too is discarded.
  - See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34326455/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is being ran in PowerShell Core (*since the tags indicate it is*), it's safe to assume you're confusing bash commands with PowerShell cmdlets. In PowerShell, you have to be mindful of [Terminating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/terminating-errors?view=powershell-7.2), and [Non-Terminating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/non-terminating-errors?view=powershell-7.2) errors.

Simply put, the reason why `ls -l 2>&1 file_doesnot_exists > /dev/null` doesn't work is because, `ls` - *alias for `Get-ChildItem`* - produces a terminating error that halts the rest of the execution since it is missing an argument. This is demonstrated in a [`Try {...} catch {...}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2) statement where the `catch` block "*catches*" terminating errors.

```
try {
    ls -l
}
catch {
    "it no workie"
}
```

Since `ls` is an alias to `Get-ChildItem`, the -`L` parameter defaults to `-LiteralPath` where it's now expecting a path and it's erroring out when ran since it wasn't provided.

Comment: My bad, I thought bash command and Powershell are the same. I'm running this commands on MacOs, so it's a bash command

Comment: @HamzaDevXX, nah, but it happens more often than not. Edit: See Mklement's answer instead.