# bash wont output to the file even though it has a '>'?

Tags: linux, bash

i have a bash script that is similar

```
cd dir
echo $1 > foo.foo
cmd 2> results.foo > results.foo
```

but nothing gets sent to results.foo.
foo.foo gets perfect data

```
 cat results.foo
```

nothing

```
cat foo.foo
```

Comment: Is "cmd"  an alias or a shell script or a function or simply a try to run an unknown command?

Comment: `cmd > results.foo 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
cmd > tesults.foo
```

the file is re-created with the output that is on STDOUT.
If you do

```
cmd 2> tesults.foo
```

the file is re-created with STDERR.

If you do both, as you did,

```
cmd 2> results.foo > results.foo
```

the first of the STDIN or STDOUT will recreate the file. Then the second of the two streams will recreate the file. So it will depend on which one is last what you will see in the file.

There are of course simple solutions (you're not the only one that needs this): make sure that both streams go into the `result.foo` (put the StDOUT output of `cmd` in `result.foo` and put the STDERR output(2) in the location where STDOUT(1) goes):

```
cmd > results.foo 2>&1
```

Or use different files for STDOUT and STERR:

```
cmd > results.out 2> results.err
```

Comment: try `{ echo hello 1>&2; echo world; } 2>&1 > results.foo` then `{ echo hello 1>&2; echo world; } > results.foo 2>&1` ; the order is important

Comment: See ["Shell redirection i/o order"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975232/shell-redirection-i-o-order) for explanations of why `2>&1` must come *after* `> results.foo`.

Comment: You're right; my bad.